# vuedraggable working until <transition-group> added, draggable element must have an item slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuedraggable

Trying out [vuedraggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuedraggable) and the items drag and sort.

```html
<draggable :list="listRows" item-key="listID" class="list-group">
  <template #item="{ element }">
    <div class="list-group-item" >
      {{ element.name }}
    </div>
  </template>
</draggable>
```

[image]

This works but if I add `<transition-group>`:

```html
<draggable :list="listRows" item-key="listID" class="list-group">
  <transition-group>
      <template #item="{ element }">
        <div class="list-group-item" >
           {{ element.name }}
        </div>
      </template>
  </transition-group>
</draggable>
```

I get the error:

> draggable element must have an item slot

[image]

I can't find any examples of how to fix this error or any explanation.

Comment: Not sure to understand the exact issue. Meanwhile you have quite some examples here (for Vue3): https://sortablejs.github.io/vue.draggable.next/#/simple