# Could not find a declaration file for module 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, npm, vuejs3

I am trying to install jquery into a Vue3 component.

```
npm install jquery --save
```

and in the component:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

However, as you can see from the picture there is an error **Could not find a declaration file for module 'jquery'** even though it exists.

I have read many posts on similar issues but can seem to get the error to go away, or access jquery from within the module.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried what the error is suggesting you and type "npm install --save-dev @types/jquery" ?

Comment: You will need to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery since you are using typescript

Comment: @valepu Yes but that does not make any difference

Comment: Show us your tsconfig.json then

Comment: @Lk77 there isn't one. As far as know I have not been using TS at all

Comment: Well that error comes from typescript, it's not a js error, you either have typescript or your ide think you have. Try to see if there is a way to disable that in your ide, try something like https://medium.com/lessons-from-debugging/remove-ts-errors-from-js-files-3970d1a5336c

Comment: @Lk77 I have never used TS. Why would VS Code think I am?

Comment: Can you post a screnshot of your project structure?

Comment: VScode has TS enabled by default. If you don't use it, you can skip the whole thing. Also, why do you even use jQuery with Vue3? Overall, more context about your project is welcome.

Comment: I was about to suggest something on the lines of @kissu have you tried running your project despite the error? Also at this point could use a screenshot of src and the content of your package.json and vue.config.js, anything will help investigating the issue

Comment: It is not an error, just an info tooltip. So not blocking the project's proper functioning.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is some information about VScode not being able to find the proper type declaration for jQuery.
Since you [don't use TS at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74886370/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-jquery?noredirect=1#comment132156306_74886370), I recommend that you skip any headache trying to troubleshoot that one and move along. Your project will work perfectly fine without explicit types.

---

PS: I don't recommend using jQuery with Vue3 in 2023. Adding 30kB of JS is not the way to go nowadays. Especially since it does not bring any significant value.

Comment: The reason for wanting to include jquery is to make use of the datepicker. I understand that it is not the best practice to include jquery in a Vue3 project but I am exploring a few options for date picking and in doing so came across this issue. I was trying to understand the cause to get a better understanding of the issue. I may not end up using jQuery - just interested in why the 'error' appears.

Comment: @RGriffiths I feel like there are [enough packages here](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#date-picker) and most of them being without jQuery. You probably have one in your CSS framework (Vuetify, bootstrap-vue, etc...) that you could use. Really no excuse to still use jQuery in 2023. It will slow you down and bring more problems to the table. Again, this is **not an error**. Mainly a TS info that you don't have the types explicitly defined. Hence the mention of `"any"` in the tooltip, which is quite a generic and un-helpful type in TS.

Comment: That is extremely helpful - thank you. I will have a look at the packages listed. Hopefully I will find one that fits the bill. Appreciate the link.

Comment: Keep us informed if your issue is not fixed and you need more details to solve your question.

Comment: Kind offer. I am currently looking at vanilla-js-datepicker. I am looking for a solution that combines well with another site, hence initally looking at jQuery. My Vue project creates html which is rendered for the other site. So a follow up to this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74891746/vue3-using-vanilla-js-datepicker

Comment: @RGriffiths got any more questions beyond the (solved) linked answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363480/vuedraggable-working-until-transition-group-added-draggable-element-must-have Would be great to get to the bottom of this one.