# Vue3 using Vanilla JS Datepicker

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vanillajs-datepicker

I am trying to use [Vanilla JS Datepicker](https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/) in a Vue3 project but unsure how to correctly set it up. As per the docs (which I realise don't specifically relate to Vue) I have installed the package:

```
npm install --save-dev vanillajs-datepicker
```

In the template:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" />
```

The script:

```
import { Datepicker } from "vanillajs-datepicker";


mounted() {
    const elem = document.getElementById("foo");
    const datepicker = new Datepicker(elem, {
      // ...options
    });
},
```

I am getting the error:

> error  'datepicker' is assigned a value but never used

UPDATE

```
<input type="text" ref="foo" />

new Datepicker(this.$refs.foo, {
  // ...options
});
```

And all is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

This is a working solution that I achieved.
I find it a bit messy already, not sure that I would use that one but it works let's say.

```html
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import "../../node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/dist/css/datepicker.min.css";
import Datepicker from "vanillajs-datepicker/Datepicker";

onMounted(() => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('input[name="date"]');
  const datepicker = new Datepicker(elem);
  console.log("picker", datepicker);
});
</script>

<template>
  <input type="text" name="date" />
</template>
```

---

That error is related to ESlint, what it means is that your variable `datepicker` is not used down the code (plenty of similar questions on this website that you can look for if you need more details).

If you use a `console.log(datepicker)` for example, it will disappear.

You can also disable that `rule` or mark it as a `warning`.

As for `elem`, you should use a template ref rather: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs
It will produce the same result as a document selector but is a better practice since you're using an SPA.

Comment: Perfect. It actually works if I just remove the definition of datepicker. Good point about $refs. Thanks once again - a great help.

Comment: @RGriffiths I've shared a Composition API example. Not exactly sure why it doesn't work with `refs` there, I don't have a lot of experience with CAPI.

Comment: Nice one. Good to see the other ways of doing it.